# i need hide an element when an especific text is showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to hide the check-out button when the text "No shipping options found for" is visible. I'm selecting by query all to get some elements, after this I select the button and I apply the style display none, but it is still showing. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```js
function hidenv() {
  var txt = document.querySelectorAll(".shipping td")[0].innerText;
  if (txt >= "No shipping options found for") {
    document.querySelectorAll(".proceed-to-checkout").forEach((element) => element.style.display = "none");
  }
}
```

```html
<tr class="shipping">
        <th>Shipment</th>
        <td data-title="Shipment">
            No shipping options found for <strong>xxxx, xxx, 0000</strong>. 
        </td>
    </tr>
      
      
    <div class="proceed-to-checkout">
            
      <a href="https://nextstep.nxt/" class="checkout-button">
        Proceed payment</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: no, the div is out side and the code no get any error

Comment: The reason of getting no error in your code is that it is not executing , so no error is thrown . If you execute it you will see a error for applying on undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because no event is defined to execute function . Here `hidenv()` at bottom works as automatic execution on load .

Also add the word you want to match in separate container so that it can be easily retrieved and matched properly .

```js
function hidenv() {

  var txt = document.querySelectorAll(".notFound")[0].innerText;
  if (txt == "No shipping options found for") {
    document.querySelector(".proceed-to-checkout").style.display = "none";
  }
}
hidenv();
```

```html
<tr class="shipping">
  <th>Shipment</th>
  <td data-title="Shipment">
    <span class="notFound">No shipping options found for</span><strong> xxxx, xxx, 0000</strong>.
  </td>
</tr>

<div class="proceed-to-checkout">

  <a href="https://nextstep.nxt/" class="checkout-button">
        Proceed payment</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rana have been share a good answer but the text showing don't have any html tag. So i did this.

First select the text inside another and and later aply the display none

```js
function hidenv() {

  var txt = document.querySelector(".shipping").querySelectorAll("td")[0].innerText;
  if (txt === "No shipping options found for") {
    document.querySelector(".proceed-to-checkout").style.display = "none";
  }
}
hidenv();
```

```html
<tr class="shipping">
  <th>Shipment</th>
    <td data-title="Shipment">
            No shipping options found for <strong>xxxx, xxx, 0000</strong>. 
    </td>
</tr>
      
      
<div class="proceed-to-checkout">
            
  <a href="https://nextstep.nxt/" class="checkout-button">
        Proceed payment</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think depending on text inside an element is not a god idea! but if you really want to do it, this is the way!
2. It's better to have div inside  and make it show and hide. Hiding a  is not the best idea.

   ```
    let theShipmentElement = $("td[data-title='Shipment']");
    if(theShipmentElement.html().indexOf('No shipping options found for') > -1){
        theShipmentElement.hide();
    }
   ```